# Network Error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5000 after a certain number of tests in react-testing library

Tags: react-testing-library

I am testing an app with react-testing-library and I am using a mock service worker.
All my tests pass until the last one which gives this error in the title.
When testing only the part which gives error isolated (test.only), then it doesn't throw error.
The error points to localhost:5000 which is my data server (my app is running on 3000)

This is my last test which only works when running alone:

```
    import { findByRole, getByRole, render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
    import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event'
    import Layout from '../../layout'

    describe('tests for headers and content of the table', () => {
      test('to check headers in inital state', async () => {
        render(<Layout />)
        const headerFirstCell = await screen.findByRole('columnheader', {name: /name/i, })   
        expect(headerFirstCell).toHaveTextContent('Name')
       const headerSecondCell = await screen.findByRole('columnheader', {name: /courses/i,}) //second
        expect(headerSecondCell).toHaveTextContent('Courses')
         })
```

It is also strange that when I run only one part of the last code + all the rest, fex:

```
const headerFirstCell = await screen.findByRole('columnheader', {name: /name/i, })   
expect(headerFirstCell).toHaveTextContent('Name')
```

Or the other part + all the rest:

```
 const headerSecondCell = await screen.findByRole('columnheader', {name: /courses/i,}) //second
 expect(headerSecondCell).toHaveTextContent('Courses')
```

Then all tests pass. It seems like any line of code I add after that point will make the error throw.

I know it might not be easy to see from this info...but I'm lost...Any clue??

Just in case this is my setupTests.js:

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'

import { server } from './mocks/server.js'

beforeAll(() => server.listen())

afterEach(() => server.resetHandlers())

afterAll(() => server.close())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just was a typo in one of the server url addresses in my mock service worker handlers.
So when testing a part which gets requests to that url it threw an error sometimes, in case I place that function at the end, the tests finished before doing the get request to the wrong url. That's why it had that strange behaviour.